# How do I make a dynamic expression out of strings in Report Builder?

Tags: reporting-services, microsoft-reporting

Basically I need to be able to construct bits of an expression out of strings and have the expression treat these strings as regular parts of the expression, and not strings.
Specifically i have a Lookup function in this format:
Lookup(source_expression, destination_expression, result_expression, dataset)
But I want the result_expression to be customisable. As in I want to take the string "Fields!"+[custom column name here]+".Value" so that i can have a custom column reference for it to pick up stuff from.

I apologise fo rthe horribly worded question; it has been a long day, and this problem is frying my brain.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a `SWITCH()` and have each of the "true-parts" be the entire lookup expression that you want for that option. I've tried to dynamically just select the field or matching expression before and it doesn't work.

It would be something like this:

```
=SWITCH(
    Parameter!selOutput.Value=1, Lookup(Fields!source.Value,Fields!match.Value,Fields!ColumnA.Value),
    Parameter!selOutput.Value=2, Lookup(Fields!source.Value,Fields!match.Value,Fields!ColumnB.Value),
    Parameter!selOutput.Value=3, Lookup(Fields!source.Value,Fields!match.Value,Fields!ColumnC.Value),
    1=1, Lookup(Fields!match.Value,Fields!lookup.Value,Fields!ColumnElse.Value)
)
```

Comment: I also considered this, but I dont have a set number of options, so can't cover all the bases with a SWITCH().